# How can I remove "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo" from pulseaudio forever?

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, firefox, xubuntu, microsoft-teams

I have periodic problems when web browser for some reason selects this "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo" input source as input. E.g. today it happened with unholy combination of microsoft teams and firefox.

How can I delete this device (sink? source?) forever? I get no benefit from its existence.

EDIT:

I don't know why msteams did pick up this source. Might be because one tab temporarily was "holding" the proper audio source (microphone)

Anyway, I want to make it gone. My logic is simple, if it's impossible to select "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo" in firefox, then I'll never have this problem. I guess I can configure firefox to ignore it, but could there be a pulseaudio solution?

I'm running xubuntu 20.04. In `pactl list` the device looks like this

```
Source #0
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 1999818 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xd04c0000 irq 84"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

EDIT2

Please don't tell me to set "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo" to output only. Because, even if this helps with removing "Monitor of ..." sound source, I will lose access to my microphone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The monitor source represents the ability to record an exact digital copy of whatever sounds your sound chip is outputting. I don't think it can be easily disabled, but also the monitor sources should default to the lowest possible priority. Could it be that you last started up Firefox and/or Teams with no other audio source plugged in? Pulseaudio will usually try and remember the devices used by each program and restore the same assignments next time, unless told otherwise by e.g. your desktop environment. Does your desktop include an audio source/sink config tool?

Comment: The `device.description` property is what will appear in the Configuration tab of `pavucontrol` (one for each actual audio device).  Then you select the desired Profile from the drop-down menu (e.g. "Analog Stereo Output" or some other output-only profile).

Comment: @cas, I can set output only mode there. But then it will disable my microphone. I guess it's a singe chip which processes input and output. My goal is to make sure it's impossible to select this "Monitor" device anywhere, not to remove all options for sound input

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up the Pulse Audio Audio Mixer (`pavucontrol`),
2. Click on the Configuration tab,
3. Click on the "Family 17h...." drop-down menu and select either "Off" (to disable it entirely) or one of the Output-only options (i.e. without the word "Input" or similar).

Check the "Input Devices" tab and the unwanted Monitor device should be gone, no other programs will ever see it again.

The procedure will probably be very similar if you use `pipewire` rather than Pulse Audio.

Note: this will probably change the name of your output device (e.g. from "Analog Stereo Output 2.1 + Analog Stereo Input" to "Analog Stereo Output" or whatever option you selected), so you'll probably need to change your default to match.

Comment: The Configuration tab will list only the base devices, e.g. mine has "Family 17h..." (my motherboard's built-in sound), "Navi 21/23 HDMI...." (my Radeon 6800), and "Edifier V4" (my USB headphone + speaker set).   I have the Navi 21/23 one set to Off (because I only want sound in or out through my motherboard or my headset).  I also used this method to disable Input from my motherboard because I don't have a microphone plugged in to it.

Comment: @mr.T If you have new info to add, please don't do it in comments but [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736308/edit) your question instead. That way the relevant info and your current situation are readily available without digging them out from comments.